# Atualizar Banco de Dados automaticamente (adicionar uma coluna) SQLite/Dart

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Bom dia, tenho um aplicativo que ja esta em funcionamento, gostaria de adicionar uma coluna ao banco de dados para quem ja esta com ele instalado automaticamente. Testei no meu celular, se eu excluir o aplicativo e instalar novamente elea faz corretamente e instala o novo banco com a nova coluna 'qtdDias'.
Vou mandar o código para ver se vocês podem me da uma força.
Eu jaá fiz um método onUpgrade, mas não sei como inicializar ele, ja tentei chamar no meto get database támbem nao deu certo.

```
class DiariaHelpers {
//criar e conectar ao banco de dados

//definindo estrutura da tabela

  String nomeTabela = 'tbDiarias';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTipo = 'tipo';
  String colLocal = 'local';
  String colDate = 'date';
  String colValue = 'value';
  String colObs = 'obs';
  String colDias = 'qtdDias';
  String colState = 'state';
  


//metodo singleton
  static DiariaHelpers? _databasehelper;
  static Database? _database;
  DiariaHelpers.createInstance();

  factory DiariaHelpers() {
    if (_databasehelper == null) {
      _databasehelper = DiariaHelpers.createInstance();
    }
    return _databasehelper!;
  }

  //verificando se o banco de dados foi inicializado
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await startDataBase();
    }else{
      _addColuna(_database!);
    }
    return _database!;
  }


  //"ALTER TABLE tbDiarias ADD COLUMN qtdDias Text;"

  //inicializa banco de dados(criar/inicializar)
  Future<Database> startDataBase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String pathDb = directory.path + '/\dbdiarias.db';
    
    var database = await openDatabase(
      pathDb,
      version: 2,
      onCreate: _createTable,
      
    );
    return database;
  }




//atualizando banco de dados
  void _addColuna(Database db) async {
    await db.execute('ALTER TABLE tbDiarias ADD COLUMN qtdDias Text'); 
  }

//ADICIONAR COLUNA
  void _createTable(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $nomeTabela ('
        '$colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
        '$colTipo Text, '
        '$colLocal Text, '
        '$colDate Text, '
        '$colValue Text, '
        '$colObs Text, '
        '$colDias Text, '
        '$colState INTEGER)');
     
  }
```

Tentei chamar o adicionar coluna quando o banco for inicializado nesse parate do código :

```
Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await startDataBase();
    }else{
      _addColuna(_database!);
    }
    return _database!;
  }
```

Mas não funcionou. Obrigado pessoal..

Answer (score -1):

Fiz esse código estou aguardando a atualização na PlayStore para ver se vai funcionar.

````
void _onUpgrade(Database database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
    if (oldVersion <= 2) {
      await database.execute("ALTER TABLE tbDiarias ADD COLUMN qtdDias Text DEFAULT 0");
    }
  }

```

Foi chamada nesse método:
```
Future<Database> startDataBase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String pathDb = directory.path + '/\dbdiarias.db';

    var database = await openDatabase(
      pathDb,
      version: 3,
      onCreate: _createTable,
      onUpgrade: _onUpgrade,
    );

    return database;
  }
```
````

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).